# How to use configure method of Grace IOC for Application Settings

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, grace-ioc

I am using [Grace](https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace) and I want to configure it to track my settings in `appsettins.json` file. I can configure that with default container of `ASP.NET Core` like the following:

```
services.Configure<DatabaseConnectionSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Database:Connection"));
```

and later use the `IOptions<DatabaseConnectionSettings>` or for reloading capability `IOptionsSnapshot<DatabaseConnectionSettings>` to get the strong-typed values from the container. How can I achieve this when using Grace? and will it support the reload capability of settings when the underlying data changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue configuring your application the exact same way. What ever is registered in the service collection will be registered automatically in Grace. I just created an sample app to test that